# Java - Remove spaces around comma outside quoted String?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String as shown below:

```
String s = "A,  Category,   \"Agriculture, forestry and fishing\",";
```

I want to remove spaces around comma (which are outside quotes). So my string should look like:

```
A,Category,"Agriculture, forestry and fishing",
```

I tried following RE:

```
String s = s.replaceAll("[,]\\s+", ",");
```

but output is:

```
A,Category,"Agriculture,forestry and fishing",
```

What changes should I do in my regular expression to avoid changes for commas inside quotes?

Comment: That looks like CSV (Comma-Separated Values) data, so use a CSV parser to parse the data and reformat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
String str = "A,  Category,   \"Agriculture, forestry and fishing\",";
String result = str.replaceAll(" (?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", "");
//------------------------------^--------------------------------------
System.out.println(result);
```

This will print :

```
A,Category,"Agriculture, forestry and fishing",
//----------------------^---------------------
```

The space inside the quotes is not changes, just outside the quotes.

---

Here is a [code DEMO](https://ideone.com/HctOK4) and here is a [regex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/0nWgtJ/1)

---

**EDIT**

This part is from **@Exception_al** so he suggest to use this :

```
String result = str.replaceAll("(\\s*,\\s*)(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", ",");
```

This solution is very good if you want to replace all spaces between comma `,` and the word.

You can check how this can work in [regex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mwM1BA/2)

Comment: Just change it to : `String result = str.replaceAll("(\s*,\s*)(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", ",");` this would take more than one space and remove it as well ... and not touch spaces between words.

Comment: haha, so you removed the up-vote for that @Exception_al , ok you can add this as an answer this can help others, but i think the OP ask about spaces so this can not work if there are many spaces between the words like `Category    of       something`, any way your solution still correct so you can add it like an answer ok

Comment: Well your answer has it all (almost) ... the idea is to answer OPs query ... I wanted to suggest an Edit but the Q is apparently full so I commented !!! You did most of the work .. you desreve the answer as well.

Comment: ok you want me to add your solution in my answer @Exception_al ?

Comment: That should answer OPs question and cover all aspects of it ... so indeed ! And nice work with Regex (positive lookahead etc.) !

Comment: thank you @Exception_al i already add it to my question i mention your name there hope this can make you happy ;)

Comment: @Exception_al , Sonar says "Make sure the regex used here, which is vulnerable to polynomial runtime due to backtracking, cannot lead to denial of service." So can you suggest some alternate solution available?